# $X=A\cup B$ be an open cover of $X$. If $X,A,B$ are simply connected , then $A\cap B$ path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm trying to prove or find counterexample to the following :

Let $X=A\cup B$ be an open cover of $X$. Assume that $X,A,B$ are simply connected , then  $A\cap B$ must be path-connected.

I tried a proof by contradiction : Assume that  $A\cap B$ not path-connected , and pick loop which start at one of the connected components, say $C_1$ , travelling through all the other  connected components , then returning to $C_1$.

I think the fact this loop is nullhomotopic will imply that A∩B is connected, but I haven't found such a proof.

(I'm not sure if that true)

Comment: Have you studied homology yet?

Comment: @RobertBell Yes

Comment: Then Mayer-Vietoris works.

Comment: @RobertBell can you elaborate please ?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply the Mayer-Vietoris sequence:

$$H_1(X)\to \widetilde{H}_0(A \cap B) \to \widetilde{H}_0(A) \oplus \widetilde{H}_0(B)$$

Since $X$ is simply connected, $H_1(X) = 0$.  Since $A$ and $B$ are simply connected, they are path connected and so their reduced 0-th homology groups are zero.  Therefore, $\widetilde{H}_0(A \cap B) = 0$ and so $A \cap B$ is path connected.  Here I am using singular homology.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interesting example to think about that doesn't prove or disprove the question.

Let $X$ be the quasi-circle shown in the figure, a closed subspace
of $\mathbb R^2$ consisting of a portion of the graph of $y = sin(1/x)$, the segment $[−1, 1]$ in the $y$ axis, and an arc connecting these two
pieces.
[image: Quasi-circle]

The important point about this example is that $X$ is simply connected even though it somewhat resembles a circle.

Now if you pick $A$ to be an open piece in the top part and $B$ to be an open piece in the bottom part, we get $B,X$ is simply connected, and $A$ is almost simply connected, i.e. all loops are null-homotopic ($A$ fails to be simply connected because it isn't path-connected). Lastly observe that $A\cap B$ is not path-connected!

Edit:
$A$ is the intersection of the pink region with the quasi-circle and $B$ is the intersection of the purple region with the quasi-circle.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Define a path connecting the point $(0,1) to a nearby point of the sine wave.

Comment: Given $A \cup B = X$, which set contains the $(0,0)$ point, and is it really simply connected?

Comment: I think more detail is needed as to what $A$ and $B$ are, I am confused.

Comment: The topologist's sine curve, which is what your example uses, and joins with an arc, is the standard example of a connected part of the plane which is not also path connnected. In particular it is not simply connected.

Comment: @coffeemath consider the path from (0,1) to (0,0) and the travels along the nice arc counterclockwise.

Comment: @aschepler, it is indeed simply connected. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3705688/to-show-that-warsaw-circle-is-simply-connected

Comment: @aschepler see the diagrams

Comment: The Warsaw circle is indeed simply connected, but the pink part is not.